# EntryPointNotFoundException in OWIN

Tags: .net, owin, katana

I have created a console application in Visual Studio 2010 and installed nuget packages such as Microsoft.Owin.Hosting and Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener for OWIN and configured like below

```
namespace KatanaIntro
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string uri = "http://localhost:8080";
            using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(uri))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Started");
                Console.ReadKey();
                Console.WriteLine("Stopped");
            }
        }
    }
    public class Startup
    {
        public  void Configuraion(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.Run(ctx=> ctx.Response.WriteAsync("Welcome to my first katana application"));
        }
    }
}
```

After running the application i got the exception **EntryPointNotFoundException**
**The following errors occurred while attempting to load the app.
 - No 'Configuration' method was found in class 'KatanaIntro.Startup, KatanaIntro, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null**

How can i resolve this?anything iam missing?

Comment: you misspelt configuration. your code -> "Configuraion". Correction -> "Configuration"

Comment: the method name as I had said.... you have misspelt Configuration

Comment: glad you got it working!

Comment: how can i call configuration directly?i think we can call this method directly method name is not a pblm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you misspelt configuration. your code -> "Configuraion". Correction -> "Configuration"

Comment: Just to add - I wrote letter c in configuration as small case and got same issue.It is fixed when I made it Configuration.Thanks.